# In what scenarios is it best to use Helm Chart to install APISIX?

Tags: apache-apisix

I'm installing APISIX according to this [article](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/how-to-build), which mentions three different installation methods: Docker RPM and helm, I'm somewhat confused about what way is it better to use the helm method to install?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy Apache APISIX[1] on Kubernetes, installing with Helm is a good option.

And the project provides an official Helm chart[2].

For example, you can use the following command to complete the installation of APISIX and APISIX Ingress[3]

```
helm repo add apisix https://charts.apiseven.com
helm install apisix apisix/apisix --set gateway.type=NodePort --set ingress-controller.enabled=true --set ingress-controller.config.apisix.serviceNamespace=apisix --namespace apisix --create-namespace --set ingress-controller.config.apisix.serviceName=apisix-admin
```

1: https://apisix.apache.org/

2: https://github.com/apache/apisix-helm-chart

3. https://github.com/apache/apisix-ingress-controller/